# Knockout Not Rendering - Simple Example

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, asp.net-core-mvc

I am learning MVC - MVVM using .NET Core in VS2019. I am following a pluralsight course and using my existing tables to try and get the hang of it....

When I introduce knockout and knockout mapping in my view from the viewmodel, it only shows the labels

[image: What actually renders...],

but not the details of the record. I am sure it is something simple, due to my lack of experience. I will post the code snippets below.

Details.cshtml

```
@model DRMS.EDX.Web.ViewModels.DataFileViewModel
@using Newtonsoft.Json

@{
ViewBag.Title = "DataFile Details";
}
@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datafileviewmodel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataFileViewModel = new DataFileViewModel(@Html.Raw(Model));
    ko.applyBindings(dataFileViewModel);
</script>
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<p data-bind="text: MessageToClient"></p>

<div>
  <div>
    <label>DataFileLayoutID :</label>
    <span data-bind="text: DataFileLayoutID"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <label>CreatedByID :</label>
    <span data-bind="text: CreatedByID"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <label>CreatedDate :</label>
    <span data-bind="text: CreatedDate"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <label>ModifiedByID :</label>
    <span data-bind="text: ModifiedByID"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <label>ModifiedDate :</label>
    <span data-bind="text: ModifiedDate"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <label>HasScheduleA :</label>




datafileviewmodel.js

DataFileViewModel = function (data) {
var self = this;
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
};




Controller

   public async Task<IActionResult> Details(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var dataFile = await _context.DataFiles
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (dataFile == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        DataFileViewModel dataFileViewModel = new DataFileViewModel();

        dataFileViewModel.Id = dataFile.Id;
        dataFileViewModel.DataFileLayoutID = dataFile.DataFileLayoutID;
        dataFileViewModel.CompanyID = dataFile.CompanyID;
        dataFileViewModel.FileTypeId = dataFile.FileTypeId;
        dataFileViewModel. FileNameID = dataFile.FileNameID;
        dataFileViewModel.MessageToClient =  "I originated from the 
            viewmodel, rather than the model.";

        return View(dataFileViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Does the broswer console report any errors?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
datafileviewmodel.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
knockout-3.5.0.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
knockout.mapping-latest.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
datafileviewmodel.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
00000035-0075-0000-0000-000000000000:157 Uncaught ReferenceError: DataFileViewModel is not defined
    at 00000035-0075-0000-0000-000000000000:157

Comment: Is there a best practice for bundling in Core 2? If so what would that be and where can I see it done?

Comment: So I am just down to this console error...Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
00000035-0075-0000-0000-000000000000:157 Uncaught ReferenceError: DataFileViewModel is not defined
    at 00000035-0075-0000-0000-000000000000:157

Comment: The 404 error means that the requested page was not found. Open the browser inspector, open the Network tab and reload the page. You should be able to see the resource not found and understand which url is called... In any case I think it is a server side issue.

Comment: I am getting a 404 on https://localhost:44350/Scripts/datafileviewmodel.js which does exist and is just the simple  code listed above. I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Assuming this is .net core is the scripts folder within your wwwroot? Also try using "value" instead of "text" within your data-bind...

Answer (score 0):

The creation of the model from the controller, will not generate a JS file, named after the model. That's why you are getting a 404 error.

If you want to pass in the model from the controller, then you don't need a separate JS file for the same purpose.

Here are the code snippets for a quick example I made and tested.

This is the controller action:

```
    public IActionResult KnockoutJS()
    {
        return View(new DataFileViewModel() {
            Id="1",
            DataFileLayoutId="file layout",
            CompanyId = "{E20B0561-3458-412C-B5FA-DB1354D40D21}",
            FileTypeId ="TEXTFILE",
            FileNameId="TEXT",
            MessageToClient = "I originated from the view model rather than the model."
        });
    }
```

This is the view and knockoutJS initialization. To answer your question accurately I added the ko.mapping code, but you shouldn't use this plugin, as it's development has been abandoned, unless you plan on maintaining it :) This example also uses jQuery. You don't have to, if you don't need it.

```
@model DataFileViewModel
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ready.then(() => {
            var mapping = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model)));
            var dataFileViewModel = {
                Id: '@Model.Id',
                DataFileLayoutId:'@Model.DataFileLayoutId',
                CompanyId: '@Model.CompanyId',
                FileTypeId: '@Model.FileTypeId',
                FileNameId: '@Model.FileNameId',
                MessageToClient:'@Model.MessageToClient'
                    };
             ko.applyBindings(dataFileViewModel, document.getElementById("bindingRoot"));
        });

</script>
}
```

You also need to make sure that knockoutJS is loaded before you try to applyBindings.

And finally here is the HTML with the bindings.

```
<div id="bindingRoot">
<p data-bind="text: MessageToClient"></p>

<div>
    <div>
        <label>Id :</label>
        <span data-bind="text: Id"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>DataFileLayoutId :</label>
        <span data-bind="text: DataFileLayoutId"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>CompanyId :</label>
        <span data-bind="text: CompanyId"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>FileTypeId :</label>
        <span data-bind="text: FileTypeId"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>FileNameId :</label>
        <span data-bind="text: FileNameId"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result in the browser
[image: Result in the browser]